# Python script runs slower when executed multiple times

Tags: python

I have a python script with a normal runtime of ~90 seconds. However, when I change only minor things in it (like alternating the colors in my final `pyplot` figure) and execute it thusly multiple times in quick succession, its runtime increases up to close to 10 minutes.

Some bullet points of what I'm doing:

- I'm not downloading anything neither creating new files with my script.
- I merely open some locally saved `.dat`-files using `numpy.genfromtxt` and crunch some numbers with them.
- I transform my data into a rec-array and use indexing via `array.columnname` extensively.
- For each file I loop over a range of criteria that basically constitute different maximum and minimum values for evaluation, and embedded in that I use an inner loop over the lines of the data arrays. A few `if`'s here and there but nothing fancy, really.
- I use the `multiprocessing` module as follows

  ```
  import multiprocessing

  npro = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  # Count the number of processors
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=npro)
  bigdata = list(pool.map(analyze, range(len(FileEndings))))
  pool.close()
  ```

  with `analyze` being my main function and `FileEndings` its input, a string, to create the right name of the file I want to load and the evaluate. Afterwards, I use it a second time with

  ```
  pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=npro)
  listofaverages = list(pool2.map(averaging, range(8)))
  pool2.close()
  ```

  `averaging` being another function of mine.
- I use numba's `@jit` decorator to speed up the basic calculations I do in my inner loops, `nogil`, `nopython`, and `cache` all set to be `True`. Commenting these out doesn't resolve the issue.
- I run the scipt on Ubuntu 16.04 and am using a recent Anaconda build of python to compile.
- I write the code in PyCharm and run it in its console most of the time. However, changing to `bash` doesn't help either.
- Simply not running the script for about 3 minutes lets it go back to its normal runtime.
- Using `htop` reveals that all processors are at full capacity when running. I am also seeing a lot of processes stemming from PyCharm (50 or so) that are each at equal `MEM%` of 7.9. The `CPU%` is at 0 for most of them, a few exceptions are in the range of several %.

Has anyone experienced such an issue before? And if so, any suggestions what might help? Or are any of the things I use simply prone to cause these problems?

Comment: did you check resource consumption of the script using `top` or something similar or even better profile the script? And if so does the memory-consumption go up each time you call it again? One possible cause might be that the "place" you run it from (IDE console or bash) holds on to some results...

Comment: have you tried profiling?

Comment: Tried to, didn't succeed. `Can't pickle <function analyze at 0x7efd1253b6a8>: attribute lookup analyze on __main__ failed`, `analyze` being my function that does the majority of the work. However, I incorporated some prints in my script that indicate that it just takes longer overall, i.e. the relative durations between the prints stay the same, they are just longer in total.

Comment: Without your code, especially your `loop ...` and the `process worker` there's nothing to tell.

Answer (score 0):

May be closed, the problem was caused by a malfunction of the fan in my machine.